# Are there some Ajax JSON testing and debugging web services/APIs?

Tags: ajax, json, web-services, jsonp, asp.net-web-api

I'm debugging some tricky Ajax code without a server side, in fact I have no domain etc to even put any server-side code on.

I would like to find some very minimal Ajax JSON(P) testing or debugging webservice or web API that just sends something back. Something like a `ping` or `noop` or `ack`.

I would prefer something small, fast, and reliable, preferably provided by major Internet companies such as Google, Microsoft, or Yahoo.

Ideally it would support these features, though none are totally essential:

- Support `JSONP`.
- Parametrically return success or various kinds of failure.
- Parametrically delay a specified time before responding.
- Parametrically support or reject `CORS` requests.
- Parametric control over HTTP headers.
- Parametrically describe the object returned.

In fact the most basic form of such a service from a major provider would also be useful for determining that Internet access is available, at least to a degree beyond `navigator.onLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) actually supports some of the features I'm looking for with their [“Echo Javascript file and XHR requests”](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html).

> To improve user experience “echo” features has been created. This allows to test XHR requests, add javascript files, create workers - all from one fiddle, so it is more transparent for the user reading the code. XHR requests are split to *HTML*, *JSON*, *JSONP* and *XML*. *[Gist](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/gist_response.html#gist-response)* and *[github](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_response.html#github-response)* responses are similar to the echo feature and go nicely in pair with storing fiddles in *[gist](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/gist_read.html#gist-read)* and *[github](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_read.html#github-read)*.

They're not really intended for use outside jsFiddle though. Some limitations:

- HTTP `POST` must be used for everything except `JSONP` and JavaScript.
- `CORS` is not supported.

Of the desired features I listed, it supports at least:

- specifying a delay
- describing an object to return